# Monge's solution to the 'transporting earth' problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

In Schrijver's [A course in combinatorial optimization](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf) (page 49, Application 3.3), I came across the *transporting earth* problem which is quoted below (replaced the French text by its English translation in footnote 10). I am having trouble in understanding why the geometric method as mentioned in the last paragraph works. It will be highly appreciated if someone can explain this.

> Monge [1784] was one of the first to consider
>   the assignment problem, in the role of the problem of transporting earth from one area to
>   another, which he considered as the discontinuous, combinatorial problem of transporting
>   molecules:
>
> When one must transport earth from one place to another, one usually gives the name of  *Déblai*
>   to the volume of earth that one must transport, & the name of *Remblai* to the space that they
>   should occupy after the transport.
>
> The price of the transport of one molecule being, if all the rest is equal, proportional to its weight
>   & to the distance that one makes it covering, & hence the price of the total transport having to be
>   proportional to the sum of the products of the molecules each multiplied by the distance covered,
>   it follows that, the déblai & the remblai being given by figure and position, it makes difference if a
>   certain molecule of the déblai is transported to one or to another place of the remblai, but that there
>   is a certain distribution to make of the molcules from the first to the second, after which the sum of
>   these products will be as little as possible, & the price of the total transport will be a *minimum*.
>
> Monge describes an interesting geometric method to solve the assignment problem in this
>   case: let $l$ be a line touching the two areas from one side; then transport the earth molecule touched in one area to the position touched in the other area. Then repeat, until all
>   molecules are transported.

EDIT: It turns out that Monge's method is not fully correct (see Carlo Beenakker's answer below). Now I have the following follow up questions:

Under what conditions does Monge's method work or fail to work?  Is it possible to characterize shapes for which Monge's method work?

Comment: It may be better known as the "mass transfer problem".

Answer (score 2):

Schrijver explains Monge's reasoning in [On the history of combinatorial optimization (till 1960)](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/histco.pdf):

> Monge [1784] described an interesting geometric method to solve this problem.
>   Consider a line that is tangent to both areas, and move the molecule
>   $m$ touched in the first area to the position $x$ touched in the
>   second area, and repeat, until all earth has been transported. Monge's
>   argument that this would be optimum is simple: if molecule $m$ would
>   be moved to another position, then another molecule should be moved to
>   position $x$, implying that the two routes traversed by these
>   molecules cross, and that therefore a shorter assignment exists.
>
> Although geometrically intuitive, the method is however not fully
>   correct, as noted by [Appell [1928]:](http://www.numdam.org/article/MSM_1928__27__1_0.pdf) "It is very easy to make the
>   figure in such a way that the routes followed by the two particles of
>   which Monge speaks, do not cross each other."

Comment: Thanks. Now I have some follow up questions (see my edits). Does Appell's paper address these?